# SQL adding unknown level to hierarchy

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to add unknown as level in hierarchy that will hold all department that are no longer valid. I have `IsCurrent = 1` and `IsActiveDepartment = 1` this means that department is current and actively in use. If any one 0 department is inactive.

I have following hierarchy:

```
  CompanyABC
     DepartmentA
     DepartmentB
     DepartmentC
```

I need `Unknown` level in the above hierarchy that holds all expired departments.

CompanyABC
      DepartmentA
      DepartmentB
      DepartmentC
      Unknown

Table structure

```
DepKey    IScurrent    DepCode DeptName    Level1Code   Level1Name   Level2COde Level2Name
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Awesome. Now.. What's  your question?

Comment: Adding one level to hiererchy Called UNKNOWN that will hold all expired department

Comment: DepKey IScurrent DepCode DeptName Level1Code Level1Name Level2COde Level2Name ...  At level two i need KNOWN in hierarchy that contains all unvalid departments

Comment: Questions normally end in a ?  mark, for example "How do I create a new column on a table? How do I update all the rows of a table that have "john" as a first name to have a null birthday?". You've stated what you want to do, but you haven't asked a question related to what youre struggling with

Comment: How do i create level unknown  that hold expired department ? :)

Comment: Please run this in Text mode (Press Ctrl T) and edit your question, pasting query  results: `SELECT TOP 20 * FROM your_table_name_here`. Remember to format it as code: highlight the text and click `{}` button

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Yasir, the problem is: You do not show enough... There are many ways to implement a hierarchy... Best was to create a [mcve] (a *stand-alone* minimal sample with instant test-code to reproduce your issue. At least you should specify some data input and the expected output together with what you've tried so far...